# red dot next to github repository

Tags: github

I searched high and low and was surprised I couldn't find an answer to this and apologize if I somehow missed it.

Some of my github repositories have red dots next to them. Does anyone know what this means?

[image]

Comment: for some reason you have to click on the link to see the picture. Not sure why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not mean anything special. They just color code the technologies that a repository uses. Red just so happens to be for HTML.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it :)